# spring boot batch to spring cloud task with multiple jobs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a spring boot batch application that has 5 unique jobs that execute by console using the command:

***java -jar artifactName jobName param1***

but now this project will be move to cloud, so I need to use **spring cloud task**. So far so good.

I know that I have to define in the main class the @enableTask and also in the application.properties define the properties:
*spring.application.name*=cloudTask

So reading the Spring documentation understand that for triggering my jobs using **spring cloud dataflow server**, can define a task that in this case i should use as **cloudTask**. But does not make sense because how will tigger it, because my application has 5 different jobs, so the question is:

how do i connect this task name with my jobs define in the application?
The logic tell me that I need to define also 5 task name, then how do I bind this task name with the respective job.

Answer (score 1):

1. With `@EnableTask` annotation, you should be able to register your batch as Task application in SCDF - Under 'Apps'
2. Once your batch appears in Apps, 
   If all jobs 5 jobs are independent, you should be able to create 5 different Composed Tasks with same App name but with different parameters,
   OR 
   If those are interlinked, then linked jobs can be combined together in 1 composed task, by providing alias and passing corresponding set of parameters, in DSL.
3. Once the composed task is launched, task execution status can be viewed under 'Task -> Executions' and corresponding to Jobs status can be viewed under 'Jobs'

To pass custom parameters to tasks, `@EnableConfigurationProperties` `@ConfigurationProperties` can be leveraged.